# Canary: Get latest revision number by version

Tags: google-chrome, chromium

I recently reported a bug in Chromium which got closed, on my version of Canary the bug is still present though.

Now I'm not sure if my Canary version includes this bugfix. If it does I'd like to update the issue.

I have the SVN revision number of the fix as well as the version number of my Canary build but I don't know how to compare them.

The revision is [157961](https://src.chromium.org/viewvc/blink?view=revision&revision=157961), my current Canary version is "31.0.1635.1 canary Aura"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can navigate to chrome://version and the revision will be on top of the page in `(Official Build XXXXX)`

Comment: @Canadian Luke Actually it does. Except that the revision I posted was for Blink but that one is also on this version page (Blink: 537.36 (@161232))
Thanks